How do I specify the PDF page size and orientation when converting image to PDF with PHP Imagick library?
I am converting an image to PDF in PHP. How do I get the image to be on an 8.5 x 11 inch portrait page? I can't seem to find a setting to do that. What I get is a PDF page that is the size of the image.
$imagick = new Imagick();
$source_handle = fopen( $source_image, 'a+' );
$imagick->readImageFile( $source_handle );
fclose( $source_handle );
$imagick->setFormat('PDF');
$output_handle = fopen( $destination_pdf, 'w' );
$imagick->writeImageFile( $output_handle );
fclose( $output_handle );


Consider using a PDF library to have full control on the generated PDF.

I think that Olivier has a point. Alternatively this question/answer might provide a hit as to what to do.

Yes, I agree with Olivier, but in my case the PDF library I have seems to crash on larger images. I didn't want to have to deal with two different PDF libraries. I ended up getting it to work with my solution below.

I ended up solving this as follows:

Open up the image file in an imagick object.
Create another imagick object that is a blank PDF with the desired dimensions and resolution.
Use the compositeImage() method to place the image on the PDF page.

The resulting page is recognized as a US letter sized page in PDF readers.
Here is my code:
$max_width = 1700;
$max_height = 2200;

$scan = new Imagick();
$scan->setResolution( 200, 200 );
$source_handle = fopen( $source_image, 'a+' );
$scan->readImageFile( $source_handle );
$scan->setImageUnits( imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH );
fclose( $source_handle );

// Resize the image if it doesn't fit on the page
$scan->setImageResolution( 200 );
$scan->resampleImage();
$image_data = $scan->identifyImage();
$original_width = $image_data['geometry']['width'];
$original_height = $image_data['geometry']['height'];
    
if ( $original_width > $max_width or $original_height > $max_height )
    { $scan->thumbnailImage( $max_width, $max_height, true); }
$final_width = $scan->getImageWidth();
$final_height = $scan->getImageHeight();

// Set up the PDF page
$pdf = new Imagick();
$pdf->newImage( $max_width, $max_height, new ImagickPixel('white'));
$pdf->setImageFormat('PDF');
$pdf->setImageUnits( imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH );
$pdf->setResolution( 200,200 );

// Place the scanned image on the PDF page
if ( $final_width > 1500 )
    { $x = 1; }
else
    { $x = 100; }

if ( $final_height > 2100 )
    { $y = 1; }
else
    { $y = 100; }
    
$pdf->compositeImage( $scan, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, $x, $y );
unset( $scan );

// Write out the PDF
if ( file_exists( $destination_pdf ) )
    { unlink( $destination_pdf ); }
$output_handle = fopen( $destination_pdf, 'w' );
$pdf->writeImageFile( $output_handle );

